# How could I exceed 320 pixels with this code?

Tags: css, responsive-design, width

I have a setup where I have a grid of pictures in a box which works well in responsive design, except for mobile (according to google mobile)

My HTML code is as follows for 2 boxes:

```
<div ID="L"><a href="box1">1</a> <a href="box2">2</a> </div>
```

And for three boxes:

```
<div ID="L"><a href="box1">1</a> <a href="box2">2</a> <a href="box3">3</a> </div>
```

But on my site I deal with more boxes than that but the code is pretty much the same except there will be more anchor tags.

My CSS to the boxes is as follows:

```
#L {width:100%;padding:0.1em;background:#EFE;color:#000}
#L A,#L SPAN{font:bold 50% Arial;text-align:right;display:inline-block;width:124px;height:124px;background-color:#220;color:#FFF}
```

Upon running tests with google, I receive the following message:

```
Size content to viewport
The page content is too wide for the viewport, forcing the user to scroll horizontally. Size the page content to the viewport to provide a better user experience.
The page content is 326 CSS pixels wide, but the viewport is only 320 CSS pixels wide. The following elements fall outside the viewport:

The element <div id="L">1 2 3 4 5 6 7…6 97 98 99 100</div> falls outside the viewport.
```

Could it be the em unit that's throwing google off? I initially used pixels but for responsive design, em and percentages seem better. and I only use it as a margin value to make the boxes not smudged together.

Anyone know for sure why google thinks my width is 326px when I made the viewport to 320px?

And this is my viewport tag that google seems to like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: The width is 100% plus the padding of 0.1em, which is slightly more than 100% in total! So the padding is 3px on both sides. Right?

Comment: Note that the default, initial width of a div is `auto`, not `100%`. `auto` neatly solves the issue of the paddings. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/4mpz0ykj/).